# A macro that looks up a value in a cell then enters a "x" into another cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula, lookup

Can someone please advise me on a macro code that will look up a value that I type in a cell.

then enter the letter x in the cell same row but 4 columns to the right of it ? then save.

Idea is to type text into the cell press a button and it looks it up then adds an x into another cell and saves the ends sub.??

```
Sub MakeTheChanges()
Dim BayControl As Worksheet Set BayControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bay control")
BayControl.Range("A" & BayControl.Range("M1").Value + 1) = "BAY CLEAR"
BayControl.Range("C" & BayControl.Range("M1").Value + 1) = ""
BayControl.Range("D" & BayControl.Range("M1").Value + 1) = "N/A"
BayControl.Range("M1") = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show us your code and explain how your code is not working compared with the behavior you expect.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks for the quick response. I do not have a code at this moment as I am very new to vba.

Comment: Try using the recorder to create a macro.  Just go to the "View" tab, select the "Macros" drop down, and choose the "Record Macro..." option.  Then try to find the data, and place the "x" manually. Then go back & hit stop.  At least this way you have some code to start with.  You can find this code in the VB Window (just hit Alt+F11)

Comment: Sub MakeTheChanges()
Dim BayControl As Worksheet
Set BayControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bay control")

BayControl.Range("A" & BayControl.Range("M1").Value + 1) = "BAY CLEAR"
BayControl.Range("M1") = ""
End Sub I did use this in another version. but the criteria I want to search is in multiple columns.so Sheet1.Range(" various columns" & Sheet1("value entered into search box").Value)="x" I don't know what to put for various columns or how to set it to to put the "x" into a certain e.g 4 columns to the right of my lookup result ??@Demetri

Comment: I am somewhat confused as to what exactly is being requested, but getting at a range 4 columns to the right can be achieved using `.offset(0,4)`.  So if we have `Sheet1.Range("A1" & Sheet1("value entered into search box"))`, then placing an "x", 4 columns to the right would be: `Sheet1.Range("A1" & Sheet1("value entered into search box")).Offset(0,4).Value="x"`

Comment: Hi Demetri. Apologies please be patient with my novice excel :P

Comment: Hi Demetri. Apologies please be patient with my novice excel :P, That is exactly what I am after as in search and value entered result. But my criteria i enter into my search box may be in A , D, G, and I column, How do I get it to search numerous columns ?? Sheet1.Range ("A1" & "D1"& "etc" & Sheet1("Search value")) Sheet1.Range("A1" & "etc" & sheet1("Search Value")).Offset (0,4).Value="x"

Comment: Ok so I tried but still not working :/ so to break it down. I want to type a number into cell E1. Click on a shape that has a macro assigned to it. This will then search the value I have entered into E1 in Column A when it finds the value this will then enter "x" into Column E on the row the value typed in cell E1 was found. The document is called TEST and the Sheet name is Sunday and this is what I tried Sub EnterthexA()

Dim TEST As Workbook
Set Sunday = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sunday")

Sunday.Range("A" & Sunday.Range("E1").Offset(0, 4).Value) = "x"

End Sub
 @Demetri

Comment: I would change `Sunday.Range("A" & Sunday.Range("E1").Offset(0, 4).Value) = "x"` to `Sunday.Range("A" & Sunday.Range("E1").Value).Offset(0, 4).value = "x"`.  But I'm also going to provide another idea, which may not be exactly what you want but may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below, as to my interpretation of what you are perhaps looking for:

```
Sub EnterThexA()

    Dim Sunday As Worksheet, xRange As Range

    ' If E1 contains an error, just give up.
    If IsError(Range("E1")) Then Exit Sub

    ' If E1 doesn't have any value, just give up.
    If Len(Range("E1").Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set Sunday = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sunday")

    ' See if you can find whatever is in range "E1" in column A, if so, set xRange to that Cell
    Set xRange = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Range("E1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

    ' If you in fact found something
    If Not xRange Is Nothing then
        ' You want the x in column E, which is 4 places to the right.
        Set xRange = xRange.Offset(0, 4)
        xRange.Value = "x"
    End If

    ' Set certain variables to nothing (just good form, not really necessary)
    Set Sunday = Nothing: Set xRange = Nothing

End Sub
```